# Processing input-stream with awk and afterwards with sed

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I want to create a html table from a tab-separated text file.
At first I try to count the columns using

```
cols=$( head -1 $1 | awk 'NR == 1 { print NF }' )
```

then edit the stream

```
sed '1i\
<HTML>\
<BODY>\
<TABLE COLS='"$cols"'>
1 s/    /<\/TH><TH>/g
1 s/.*/<TR><TH>&<\/TH><\/TR>/
1! s/   /<\/TD><TD>/g
1! s/.*/<TR><TD>&<\/TD><\/TR>/
'
```

My problem is, that the first line of the input-file is missing while processing the sed command.

Any hints for feeding sed also with the first line? A portable solution for any shell is appreciated.

Update:
script is called:
$ ./script

The first line of data contains the headlines of the columns, and this line is missing.

Comment: What does it mean: "the first line of the input-file is missing"? Does that mean that the table header does not come from the input file but from somewhere else (hardcoded, different file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using awk. Its output [validates](http://validator.w3.org/) with no warnings. The validator says "cols" isn't a valid attribute, so I left it out.

You might want to use a function to build the table rows, passing it the tag for the kind of row you're building--either "th" or "td".

```
# html-table.awk -- create a web page with an html table from a tab-delimited file.
BEGIN {
  FS = "\t";
  print "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"";
  print "  \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">";
  print "<html>";
  print "<head>";
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\">";
  print "<title></title></head>";
  print "<body>";

}
NR == 1 {
  print "<table>";
  print "<tr>";
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    printf("<th>%s</th>\n", $i);
  }
  print "</tr>";
}
NR > 1 {
  print "<tr>";
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    printf("<td>%s</td>\n", $i);
  }
  print "</tr>";
}
END {
  print "</table>";
  print "</body>";
}
```